Is it robust to check failure on std::ofstream object itself rather than on is_open()?
If I construct a std::ofstream object by passing in a string, is it well defined to test on the object itself? I cannot seem to find a definitive answer as both seem to be used.
The documentation appears to say that the object is created and then opened when I use that constructor and then certain bits are set if it fails.
i.e.
std::ofstream File("Cannotcreate");
 if(!File){
 std::cerr << "error opening \n";
}

vs.
std::ofstream File("Cannotcreate");
 if(!File.is_open()){
 std::cerr << "error opening \n";
}

Is the first way equally as valid?

Define "equally valid".   The second will only produce an error message on failure to open the file (unless you write additional code to check other error conditions).    The first will produce an error message when any error on the stream occurs (failure to open the file is only one type of error among several - there are others) but will not provide information about what error has occurred.

Constructor with initialization will indeed construct the std::ofstream object and try to open the file. If anything corrupts the stream and puts it into invalid state not ready for input/output operations, error flags will be set (badbit, failbit, ...).
std::ofstream File("Cannotcreate");
if(!File){
std::cerr << "error opening \n";
}

In the example above, you are effectively casting an std::ofstream object to boolean (operator!), which check for any error flags. If any of the flags are set (badbit, failbit) it returns true (the stream is not ready for use and is corrupted). It is equivalent to the expression !fail() (returns the opposite of what the fail method returns).
std::ofstream File("Cannotcreate");
if(!File.is_open()){
std::cerr << "error opening \n";
}

The other example is calling the is_open method and checks only whether the file is open. The given method doesn't do any checks on the internal state of stream but only serves the purpose of cheking if there is an associated file.
If you are only checking whether the file is open, both ways are equally valid.

What could be a practical reason for !file and !file.is_open() having different values right after stream construction?
